# Initialize variables outside the constructor

Tags: c#

I want to create a small static class in C#.

This class only needs a list and a bool.

What's the difference between initializing the list and setting the default value of my bool (false) outside of any methods, like that:

```
class MyClass
{
    static bool A = true;
    static List<int> B = new List<int>();
}
```

and initializing them inside a method, like that:

```
class MyClass
{
    static bool A;
    static List<int> B;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        A = true;
        B = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your first approach, fields will be assigned the values on the first reference of your static class.

In your second approach, fields will not be assigned **your** values until you call your method `Initialize`. They will be assigned default values.

This would be different case if you have a static constructor with your class like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static bool A;
    public static List<int> B;

    static  MyClass()
    {
        A = true;
        B = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

If you want to initialize `public` fields then you can use [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) which will be called automatically when any static members is referenced. *(Please note that in this case, your fields would be `public`)*

See: [Static Constructor - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to
>   perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It
>   is called automatically before the first instance is created or any
>   static members are referenced.

Comment: True. I hadn't actually noticed that the method wasn't a constructor. I didn't bother to read the signature and just assumed it was. ;-)